# .NET metadata hidden method implementations

Tags: c#, methods

This is a beginner question.  I am sort of new to development and am curious to know.  Does Microsoft and other 3rd party developers hide the implementation details of their class methods so we can't see what is going on under the hood.  Example:

[![Example][1]][1]

This is in the public sealed class LogManager in the log4net namespace.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: public static void ShutdownRepository(string repository);

Comment: Depends on third-party developer. Some publish their code on github to provide highest visibility, others obfuscate it to prohibit (or at least complicate) getting the sources even from compiled code (or am I totally missing what obfuscation would do?). Regarding Microsoft, they released some of their code to github: http://microsoft.github.io/

Comment: Not sure what your example is meant to be doing but I'm pretty sure it isn't doing it and I'm not sure I understand the question without seeing an example of what you mean. In case you are unaware the source for .NET framework can be found at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ so they definitely don't hide a lot of things though of course you won't find the source of things like office or windows around.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, but your .NET code (e.g. C# or VB) is compiled to CIL package (Common Intermediate Language), and some metadata of your types and methods are included inside the package but not your native language implementations. The logic there is inside the package too, of course, but now it is defined by CIL ([Common Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)).

You can use some tools like reflectors (e.g. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77/) to decompile the code, for example, to more readable C# code. But remember, it is not the same code was originally created, but the logic is.

Some .NET code is open source now, like ASP.NET so you can find the source code of that in some public repositories.